# How to disable "no speakers or headphones are plugged" in tray notification?

Tags: windows-7, audio, notifications

I recently got a new machine at work and it has Windows 7 on it. The problem is the little red dot with a cross saying that "no speakers or headphones are plugged". I know it's so, as I didn't plug any. And I wouldn't. Is there a way to disable this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really simple.  You either have no speakers or headphones plugged in which is indicated by the icon... or you do.  This really isn't a warning, but rather a status update.  You could hide the icon if it bothers you that much.

Start by right clicking the "up-arrow" on the tray icon container thingie:

[image: try icon container]

And go to properties.  From there, switch the "Volume" to "Off":

[image: System Icons]

Hit "Ok" and after that, you will no longer have the volume icon.  You can reverse the process to re-enable it.

Comment: Yes, exactly, but how do I hide it?

Comment: Oh, you mean just hide it from the tray? So it remains red, but I wouldn't see it unless going deep into settings. Hm. That might work.

Comment: Added directions for disabling the icon.